# Generate a new array from an array of numbers

Tags: algorithm

I found this question on [Glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Generate-a-new-array-from-an-array-of-numbers-Start-from-the-beginning-Put-the-number-of-some-number-first-and-then-that-QTN_192467.htm):

> Generate a new array from an array of numbers. Start from the beginning. Put the number of some number first, and then that number. For example, from array 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1 You should get 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1 Write a program to solve this problem.

I am not sure if I get the idea, how come 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1 transforms into 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1? I first thought they are number of occurrences of a number followed by the number itself. But from the given example, it seems like something else is wanted.

What is this transformation?

Comment: What they are trying to say is _"Take a list of numbers. Count how many times each number occurs in the list, and create a new list that lists each number's count"._

Comment: Its a bit ambiguous. The number of times a number appears consecutively or the number of times a number appears after that number? Both gives the same result. I dont think this question is fit for SO.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it is closer to what you described, but instead of counting each numbers frequency, you have to reset your counter when you encounter with a different element in the array. check the last number 1. it caused 1,1 at the end of the result list.

Comment: ok, so this may be creepy for some people :p  this sequence is called a look-and-say sequence.  there is a theorem called the cosmological theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosmologicalTheorem.html.... oooo spooky :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I first thought they are number of occurrences of a number followed by the number itself.

Your first thought was correct.

Break the first array down to be:

```
1, 1, 
2, 
3, 3, 
1
```

And the second to be:

```
2, 1,
1, 2,
2, 3,
1, 1
```

Then it should make more sense.

Sample implementation:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

array = map(int, sys.argv[1:])
print array

count = 0
current = array[0]
index = 1
output = []
for number in array:
    if current != number:
        output.append(count)
        output.append(current)
        current = number
        count = 0
    count += 1
output.append(count)
output.append(current)

print output
```

Demo:

```
> ./arrays.py 1 1 2 3 3 1   
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

Comment: oh, thanks! i was confused about the last 2 1's, it makes much sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

what u think is correct. its the number of times the distinct element comes and then the element itself.

---

here is pseudocode:

```
array1 = given input array
array2 = output array

int previous = array1[0];
int currentCount = 0;

for each entry x in array1 {
     if(x == previous) {   
           currentCount++;
      }
     else {
          array2.add(currentCount);
          array2.add(x);   
          //reset global variables for next elements       
          previous = x;
          currentCount = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Supposing the `array1[0] == INT_MAX`?

Comment: no, just trying to have some value which is not in the array1.

Comment: but in your code, if we have 1,1,2.. it will first put 1,1,.. instead of 2,1,... because when we first encounter 1, it it not equal to previous variable and we end up adding it to the result array. but second time, we encounter 1 again, this time it is equal to previous but the counter is 0.. so it wont output 2,1,... right?

Comment: if you initialize previous variable with arr[0] i think it will fix the problem i mentioned.

Comment: true! I missed that one. thanks for correction. u know its too late in California 1:45am and coding is horror at the moment :-)

Comment: well, it is 4:49am here :D but i just implemented it and it doesnt work. because current element you are adding in else condition is the next element. e.g. we started from 1 and it's counter is = 2 when we encounter 1 in the second time. but then we iterate to the 3rd element and we fall into the else condition and we add the current element to the result list. which is 2 instead of 1. also currentCount should be initialized to 1 in else condition because since we already encountered with a new element, its counter should be +1.

Answer (score 0):

And the Haskell version...yup, that's the whole thing.

```
import Data.List
countArray list = concat [[length l, fromIntegral (head l)] | l <- group list]
```